# Q. How to transpose every nth rows using VBA

Tags: vba, transpose

Can someone suggest me how to transepose every nth row to multiple column using VBA.
i have data similar to this about 10000 rows (every transpose row need to do after '##')

dataset
|-|
|-|
|##|
|text1|
|text2|
|text3|
|text4|
|##|
|text5|
|    text6
|   text7
|    ##
|    text8
|    text9
|    text10
|    text11
|    ##
|    Text12
|    text13
|    ...

result (using ' | ' for seperate each column in excel [ A | B | C | D...])

| - | - | - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ## | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 |
| ## | text5 | text6 | text7 |  |
| ## | text8 | text9 | text10 | text11 |
| ## | text12 | text13 | ... |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, i As Long, m As Long, k As Long, mx As Long
    a = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 100)
    i = 1
    Do Until a(i, 1) = "##" And i >= UBound(a, 1)
        If a(i, 1) = "##" Then m = m + 1: k = 1
        b(m, k) = a(i, 1)
        If mx < k Then mx = k
        k = k + 1
        If i = UBound(a, 1) Then Exit Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("D1").Resize(m, mx).Value = b
End Sub
```

Comment: Then please mark as answered.